# How to display specific symbols according to the value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Nice to see all of u my friend.

Now I met some problems about Google sheet. I want to display specific symbol according to the value.
If the number is greater than 91, then it can display ✅; if the number is between 51 and 90, it can display ✔️; if the number is smaller than 51, then it displays ❌.

For example, the column A is
100 minutes,
80 minutes,
40 minutes;
......

then I want the cells can display:
✅
✔️
❌
......

Do you know how to achieve this by Google formulas?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please show what you tried. Ref. [ask].

Comment: Does column A contain the only number as 100, 80, 40 .. or it contains 100 minutes, 80 minutes, 40 minutes; like data?

Comment: It contains 100 minutes, but it can be edited as 100,80,40. Now I just wonder how to achieve displaying specific according to value...

Answer (score 2):

It's a job for vlookup formula (actually the same as in Excel)

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,$D$3:$E$5,2,TRUE)
```

[image]

And you copy down this formula

First you make a small dictionary of symbols and ranges corresponding to them (column D and E), then you use VLOOKUP that takes value from A column and checks a value found there against table in D,E and returns content of 2nd column of this range. It can be a number, string, symbol or an image.

If you want to use this formula for whole column, you can wrap it into arrayformula and array_constrain.

```
=array_constrain(ArrayFormula(ifna(VLOOKUP(A2:A,$D$3:$E$5,2,TRUE),"")),count(A2:A),1)
```

[image]

For the moment this works for number values. If you want to use time values, you should change thresholds in your dictionary into time values.

#### Reference:

- [VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en)

Comment: Thank u so much! It works so well. BTW, could u please tell me how it works? because I want to learn more. Thank u so much~~~

Comment: I have one more question... What should I do if I put the D2:E5 to another sheet?

Comment: If you wanna move your D2:E5 to another sheet then you need to change the same in `VLOOKUP` formula reference

Comment: HI, please read the reference to vlookup formula. It basically works like this: vlookup(value,table with values sorted,number of column which you want to be displayed from the table,switch true/false) switch works like this:  true - for looking up the first value that meets condition 0-49, 50-89, 90 and up, false for searching exact value (returns error N/A if value is not present)